# Proper definition of a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I just read a very short definition of a field where it was said that a field is a set of elements $K$ with two maps from the field into the field itself, such that

$K$ is an abelian group with $+$.

$K \backslash \{0\}$ is an abelian group with $\cdot$.
Furthermore, we have the distributive law $x(y+z)=xy+xz$.

Is this already sufficient to show that $0x=0$?

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: BTW,here's an even shorter definition of a field: A field F is a commutative division ring ( i.e. for every x,y in F, if x*y =0, then either x =0 or y=0 or both).

Comment: Just for the benefit of users who don't have enough rep to see comments on deleted answers: the issue here is that it's only assumed that $xy=yx$ when $x$ and $y$ are *nonzero*, so that one can't take the reversed distributive law $(y+z)x=yx+zx$ for granted if zero is involved.

Comment: Doesn't a field really have that the multiplication is commutative? Then right and left distributivity imply each other. I think the definition given is not quite right, as it is missing this.

Comment: @Dom $K\setminus\{0\}$ is an abelian group.

Comment: @egreg I don't see how that would give you $0x=x0$ or right distributivity unless you specify that it is also a ring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show that $0=x-x=x(1-1)=x0$ which is the other way around than what you wanted. To get $0x=0$ I think you will need to add that multiplication is commutative (which I believe you need to properly define a field) or alternatively that multiplication is also right distibutive. Another (short) definition of a field would be a commutative ring so that the non-zero elements form a group under multiplication.